# Can I use alternatives to manage multiple installs of Java on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, java

## TLDR

On some Linux systems (RedHat/CentOS based), I have found the UNIX **[alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives)** program being used to manage different versions of java.  One of my systems is Ubuntu 20.04, and the alternatives program doesn't exist.

My question is **can I use the alternatives program with Ubuntu 20.04?**

If so, how do I install it?  I tried installing as shown below and it couldn't be found.

```
sudo apt install alternatives
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package alternatives
```

NOTE: a similar name `sudo apt install galternatives` (a GUI version of alternatives?) did install so I'm looking at that.  It might work well enough.

A related question is
**(Q) Can I run the alternatives program on any version of Linux or does it only work with a particular Linux package manager?  Previously, I used it with CentOSs `yum install` command.**

### How does Alternatives work?

See this article https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/alternatives-command.  I'll include examples described in it so this question stands alone (if that link stops working):

After alternatives is installed I should be able to:

(1) Install multiple versions of applications.  As long as each version is installed into a different directories then I can use alternatives.

(2) Configure the alternatives program to know how where different versions of your app are installed.

In this case one is in `/opt/em-legacy/em2` and the other is in `/usr/local/bin/nem`.  I'll give it the name uemacs, and tell alternatives to make it available in `/usr/bin/em` so I don't need to change my path to run it.

> $ sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/em uemacs /opt/em-legacy/em2 1
>
> $ sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/em uemacs /usr/local/bin/nem 99

(3) Tell alternatives which version of the app you want to use.  This is done using the `alternatives --config` command as shown below.

```
$ sudo alternatives --config uemacs
[sudo] password for seth: 

There are 2 programs which provide 'uemacs'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/local/bin/nem
   2           /opt/em-legacy/em2
```

There is more to it that is explained in the referenced article.

### Background Information for my question

For years, I've managed my Java installs manually and would unzip/untar the Java package and when it needed to be updated repeat the unzip/untar into a new directory and manage symlinks to point to the version I was most predominately using.

Enter cloud... I'm so freakin tired of installing Java manually, I've got to find another (easier) way.   *Alternatives* seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian based distro you can use two command lines tools to manage java version:

1. [`update-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html)

Here is my [answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/635014/153195) for the usage of `update-alternatives`.

2. [`update-java-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/update-java-alternatives.8.html)

The `galternatives` is the graphical  setup tool for the `update-alternatives` cli.